# asp.net core app.UseExceptionHandler() to handle exceptions for certain endpoints?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, exception, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm adding some web API methods to an existing ASP.NET Core web app.  This means my new web API controller(s) will have the attribute `[ApiController]` and calling clients will expect the return output to be JSON instead of regular HTML.

In another project, I implement a custom exception handler using `app.UseExceptionHandler(...)` which encodes the response in JSON, giving information about the exception.  In this one, I want to do that, but only when the exception came from an action method inside an `[ApiController]` controller; otherwise I still want to use `app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");`, as the exception came from a regular page and the response should be HTML.

Is there a way I can set up an exception handler so that it knows where the exception came from, and render the response accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ASP.Net Core 6 you could get the `Endpoint` from the `IExceptionHandlerFeature`, until then you can capture the `Endpoint` yourself after Routing middleware and store it in a feature and use that in exception handler code.

```
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
app.UseRouting();
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    var feature = new EndpointFeature
    {
        Endpoint = context.GetEndpoint()
    };
    context.Features.Set(feature);
    await next();
});
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.Map("/Error", context =>
    {
        var feature = context.Features.Get<EndpointFeature>();
        var endpointMetadata = feature.Endpoint.Metadata;
    });
});
```

Comment: Not sure why you create a feature for this rather than just sticking the endpoint info in Items...

Comment: Items itself is implemented in Features. https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7833#issuecomment-392857949

Answer (score 3):

May I know which version are you using ASP.Net Core? [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-5.0) might be helpful for you.
Exception Handler Middleware for ASP.Net Core Web Api

```
var exceptionHandlerPathFeature =
        HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();
     var context = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
     var detail = context.Error.StackTrace;
     var message = context.Error.Message;
        if (exceptionHandlerPathFeature?.Error is FileNotFoundException)
        {
            ExceptionMessage = "File error thrown";
            _logger.LogError(ExceptionMessage);
        }
        if (exceptionHandlerPathFeature?.Path == "/index")
        {
            ExceptionMessage += " from home page";
        }
```

Comment: How does that code let me determine whether the controller the exception came from has the `ApiController` attribute?  And I'm using ASP.NET Core 3.1.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @Jez Can you try using ExceptionHandlerFeature and it will give you the controller name from where the exception has occured. I've updated the code.

Comment: @Priyanka How is that supposed to give the controller name?  It only has `Path` and `Error`.  Path is not the same thing as controller name, and the path to a controller can change when routing changes.

Comment: @Jezz Hi, can you please try using  throw new ArgumentException(
            $"Exception thrown from {variablename}.", nameof(variable)); Here's the [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

Answer (score 2):

> In this one, I want to do that, but only when the exception came from
> an action method inside an [ApiController] controller; otherwise I
> still want to use app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");, as the
> exception came from a regular page and the response should be HTML.

From your description, it seems that you want to detect where the exception come from, and if the exception come from the API method, you will use the custom exception handler with custom response, otherwise it will show the error message via the `Home/Error` page.

In this scenario, an alternative to a custom exception handler page is to provide a lambda to UseExceptionHandler. Using a lambda allows access to the path of the request that made the error before returning the response.

For example:

```
//app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
app.UseExceptionHandler(errorApp =>
{
    errorApp.Run(async context =>
    { 
        var exceptionHandlerPathFeature =
            context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();
        //check if the handler path contains api or not.
        if (exceptionHandlerPathFeature.Path.Contains("api"))
        { 
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError; ;
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";

            await context.Response.WriteAsync("<html lang=\"en\"><body>\r\n");
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("ERROR From API!<br><br>\r\n");

            await context.Response.WriteAsync(
                                            "<a href=\"/\">Home</a><br>\r\n");
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("</body></html>\r\n"); 
        }
        else
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error");
        }
    });
});
```

The result as below:

[image]

More detail information, see [Exception handler lambda](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-5.0#exception-handler-lambda) and [Asp .Net Core How to handle error pages in area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56772155/asp-net-core-how-to-handle-error-pages-in-area).

Comment: I already considered this, and I'd rather not rely on the path if possible, as routing can be changed easily.  I'd rather have some reference to the actual class/method that caused the exception.

Comment: "I'd rather have some reference to the actual class/method that caused the exception", you could try to create two custom exception classes for throwing application specific exceptions, one for API and one for the MVC, then, in the action method use try-catch statement and throw the custom exception, then in the Exception handler method check the exception type, then based on the result change the response.