# Asp.net core exception handling in applications that combines Razor Pages and ApiControllers

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, razor-pages

when using asp.net applications that combines Razor Pages and Api Controllers.
how to globally check if the exception is thrown from an Api Controller ?

the idea is to use `UseExceptionHandler` midlleware but conditionally return an html response if the unhanded exception is thrown from a Razor Page and a json `ProblemDetails` response if the excpetion is thrown from an ApiController

Comment: What do you mean "check if the exception is thrown"? Are you looking for a global exception handler for all API controllers?

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: I'm targeting netcoreapp3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For web Api, add attribute route with Api, and then check the request path in the middleware or exception handler like this:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error"); //handle the exception from the razor page

//handle the exception from the API.
app.UseWhen(context => context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"), subApp =>
{
    subApp.UseExceptionHandler(builder =>
    {
        builder.Run(async context =>
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError; 
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json"; 
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("{\"error\":\"Exception from API!\"}");
            //await context.Response.WriteAsync("ERROR From API!<br><br>\r\n"); 
            //await context.Response.WriteAsync("<a href=\"/\">Home</a><br>\r\n");
            //await context.Response.WriteAsync("</body></html>\r\n");
        });
    });
});
```

The result as below:

[image]

Besides, you can also use a custom exception handler page is to provide a lambda to UseExceptionHandler. Using a lambda allows access to the path of the request that made the error before returning the response.

For example:

```
//app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
app.UseExceptionHandler(errorApp =>
{
    errorApp.Run(async context =>
    { 
        var exceptionHandlerPathFeature =
            context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();
        //check if the handler path contains api or not.
        if (exceptionHandlerPathFeature.Path.Contains("api"))
        { 
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError; ;
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";

            await context.Response.WriteAsync("<html lang=\"en\"><body>\r\n");
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("ERROR From API!<br><br>\r\n");

            await context.Response.WriteAsync(
                                            "<a href=\"/\">Home</a><br>\r\n");
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("</body></html>\r\n"); 
        }
        else
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error");
        }
    });
});
```

More detail information, see [asp.net core app.UseExceptionHandler() to handle exceptions for certain endpoints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68256255/asp-net-core-app-useexceptionhandler-to-handle-exceptions-for-certain-endpoint/68267750#68267750)