# Global Exception Handling with .NET Core 7

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-7.0, asp.net-core-middleware

I am working on a .NET Core 7 application where I want to capture any unexpected error and send back specific details along with a 500 status code. To accomplish this, I implemented a middleware instance that is supposed to run a `try/catch`, but when I trigger an unexpected exception, the catch block never actually catches the error and the raw error (along with stack trace) is returned in a `text/plain` response (with a 500 server error).

Here is the `Invoke` method within the middleware:

```
public virtual async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    try
    {
        await this.RequestDelegate.Invoke(context);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // check whether we've started the response yet
        if (!context.Response.HasStarted)
        {
            // since we haven't, create the response model
            var model = new UnhandledExceptionModel(ex);
            var response = new ObjectResult(model)
                    {
                        StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError
                    };

            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

            await context.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(response).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        else
            throw;
    }
}
```

Via debugging, I've confirmed that this line:

```
await this.RequestDelegate.Invoke(context)
```

does run, so I know the middleware has been loaded, but the associated `catch` never gets hit. I also tried using an `ExceptionHandler`, but that also didn't hit any breakpoints and the response wasn't JSON.

Here's what it looked like:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler(a => a.Run(async context =>
        {
            var error = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>().Error;

            var model = new UnhandledExceptionModel(error);
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

            await context.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(model);
        }));
```

I assume I'm missing some small step here, but I can't seem to figure out where it's going wrong. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE 1**

The middleware is called `ExceptionHandlingMiddleware` and is currently the only middleware configured, but it inherits from a base class called `BaseMiddleware`. Here's the full definition:

```
public class ExceptionHandlingMiddleware : BaseMiddleware
{
    public ExceptionHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        : base(next)
    {
    }
}
```

Definition of `BaseMiddleware`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents the base class for middleware implementations
/// </summary>
public abstract class BaseMiddleware : IMiddleware
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents the delegate responsible for the request.
    /// </summary>
    public RequestDelegate RequestDelegate { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Instantiates an instance of this middleware with
    /// a corresponding RequestDelegate.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="next"></param>
    public BaseMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.RequestDelegate = next;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents the method to call when utilizing
    /// a middleware solution.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The HttpContext associated with the request.</param>
    /// <returns>A Task.</returns>
    public virtual async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await Task.Run(() => this.RequestDelegate.Invoke(context));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //check whether we've started the response yet
            if (!context.Response.HasStarted)
            {
                //since we haven't, create the response model
                var model = new UnhandledExceptionModel(ex);
                var response = new ObjectResult(model)
                {
                    StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError
                };

                context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

                await context.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(response).ConfigureAwait(false);

                //send the 500 error back as our model
                //var routeData = context.GetRouteData();
                //var actionDescriptor = new ActionDescriptor();
                //var actionContext = new ActionContext(context, routeData, actionDescriptor);
                //await response.ExecuteResultAsync(actionContext);
                //return;
            }
            else
                throw;
        }
    }
}
```

The `IMiddleware` interface just exposes two properties:

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents the core structure of a middleware provider.
/// </summary>
public interface IMiddleware
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents the delegate responsible for the request.
    /// </summary>
    RequestDelegate RequestDelegate { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents the method to call when utilizing
    /// a middleware solution.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The HttpContext associated with the request.</param>
    /// <returns>A Task.</returns>
    Task Invoke(HttpContext context);
}
```

Inside Startup.cs there is the standard `Configure` method - here's my full one:

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    //enables callers from anywhere
    app.UseCors("AllowAnyOrigin");

    app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandlingMiddleware>();

    //setup an exception handler so even with hard exceptions,
    //we get a consistent response with a model.
    //this handler is never called
    app.UseExceptionHandler(a => a.Run(async context =>
    {
        var error = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>().Error;

        var model = new UnhandledExceptionModel(error);
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

        await context.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(model);
    }));

    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API Docs");
        c.EnableTryItOutByDefault();

    });

    app.UseSession()
       .UseHttpsRedirection()
       .UseRouting()
       .UseAuthorization()
       .UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
       {
           endpoints.MapControllers();
       });

    //attach the HttpContext so the backend can track things like caller IP address
    var httpContext = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
    Core.HttpContext.Configure(httpContext);
}
```

My example for `app.UseExceptionHandler` came from an existing SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68267750/84839, but unfortunately it never gets called. Out of curiosity - could this be an issue with using a n-tier setup since the exception is hit inside that layer? I'm not doing anything special (no async, no threading and no `Task.Run` instances), but maybe because I'm not using async methods it's not able to snag it?

I'm going to try and play with some samples to see if I can get a smaller version of this running that's reproducible.

**UPDATE 2**

I tried directly throwing an exception right inside the endpoint handler, but the response was still the raw stack trace. I also commented out `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage`, but all that did was ensure I received the 500 server error with no response. Here's the endpoint I tried that on:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public IActionResult GetById(long id)
{
    throw new ApplicationException();
}
```

Comment: Hi,@Scott Salyer,could you show the middleware pipeline in program.cs? Have you  called other Exception Handling middleware after your cuntomer middleware?

Comment: Please show full [mre]. Was not able to reproduce, the `app.UseExceptionHandle` approach works just fine to me.

Comment: Change `await this.RequestDelegate.Invoke(context)` to `await Task.Run(() => this.RequestDelegate.Invoke(context));`, then check if it works or not

Comment: @RuikaiFeng done! I added all relevant code - middleware and the startup.cs setup that enables the middleware.

Comment: @GuruStron Hopefully the updated code covers what you're looking for. I always try to provide as much detail as possible, but with the update it's everything I've got. I'll be trying to create a direct sample later today to see if I can fully reproduce it in a much smaller app.

Comment: @JasonPan I assume that was supposed to be for the middleware, so I tried it but no luck unfortunately.

Comment: check out this one from my project which is actually working: https://github.com/orso-co/Orso.Arpa.Api/blob/develop/Orso.Arpa.Api/Middleware/ErrorHandlingMiddleware.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took some creative digging (thanks to the numerous tips posted), but I finally tracked down what was going on! The relevant code plays into `app.UseEndpoints` - for whatever reason, adding your middleware after this won't allow it to be called, so no breakpoints were being hit and it wasn't executing. Once I put it above that line, breakpoints were hit and I could handle the exceptions as expected. Here's the final section from within `Configure` in Startup.cs:

```
//enables callers from anywhere
app.UseCors("AllowAnyOrigin");

//app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "TMAC Lawn Equipment System API");
    c.EnableTryItOutByDefault();

});

app.UseSession();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();

//put middleware here, before UseEndpoints to ensure it gets called
app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandlingMiddleware>();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

Comment: Also try `app.UseEndpoints(....)` -> `app.MapControllers()` (order is still important.)

Comment: Also it pretty matched my answer - order of registration is important, if middleware in the middle of the pipeline handles the request (error or not), it usually will not execute the later register ones.

Comment: Exception-handling delegates should be called early in the pipeline, so they can catch exceptions that occur in later stages of the pipeline. see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 1):

Remove:

```cs
app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
```

Order of registration of middleware is important, with current order middleware added by `UseDeveloperExceptionPage` will handle errors before the other exception handler(s).

Comment: I tried commenting that out entirely, but then I just get a 500 error with no response text.

Comment: @ScottSalyer can you please post a full [mre] solution somewhere like github -  I will try to look in evening (5-6 hours from now).

Comment: @ScottSalyer  Also note - _"You should not throw an `ApplicationException` exception in your code, and you should not catch an `ApplicationException` exception unless you intend to re-throw the original exception."_ - [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.applicationexception?view=net-7.0)

Comment: I'll work on getting that posted - might be a few days, but I appreciate the help! Regarding the application exception - that was just an intentional throw to see if the n-tier side was causing issues, but not something I actually use :-)

Comment: @ScottSalyer better throw ordinary `Exception`. I understand that it was for the sake of sample, but still.